# Mono<User> to User in a reactive way

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a Mono object `Mono<User>` which I want to convert to object in a reactive way.

```
context.getUser().map(User::getUserId);
```

Here, `context.getUser()` returns `Mono<User>` and I can get `userId` from there. How to get the complete object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
context.getUser().map(user -> {
  // here you have the "complete" user object in variable "user"
});
```

if you need to store the value in a variable, you *can* do it like

```
User user = context.getUser().block();
```

but that's not advisable:

> you should avoid this by favoring having reactive code end-to-end, as
> much as possible. You MUST avoid this at all cost in the middle of
> other reactive code, as this has the potential to lock your whole
> reactive pipeline.

Doing that kinda defeats the point of using reactive programming. It will then have a blocking bottleneck which is exactly the thing reactive programming attempts to avoid.

Comment: I just need to return the user. Requirement is to store the user like, User usr = context.getUser().map ...

Comment: @user1578872 ah, but that's a different problem then. your requirements don't really work with reactive programming.